# Extrinsic curvature tensors

Tags: manifolds, tensors

I risk of sounding too vague, but I am interested if there are other tensors reflecting the extrinsic geometry of a submanifold other than the second fundamental form?
The first fundamental form contains information about the intrinsic geometry of the submanifold, but I'm wondering if there are other (different from second fundamental form) tensors which would "contain" information as viewed from "outside" the submanifold.

Comment: have you in mind some specific pair of manifold-submanifold?

Comment: I'm working with hypersurfaces, but more general examples are also welcome.